# Ubuntu shell script - root authorization

Tags: linux, ubuntu, sudo

I am using a shell script to execute a series of commends every time I boot my computer.

One of the commands in the script is

```
sudo insmod blablabla
```

This command needs to be run as root, so double clicking the .sh file and choosing run is not an option, I have to choose run in terminal, and then enter the password in the terminal.

Is there any way to go around that?

Also, if yes, will it work if I add the script to the startup processes so that I don't have to run it every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leverage `sudoers` to run the command as a normal user. Refer to the Ubuntu community wiki on [sudoers](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Sudoers)

Answer (score 3):

Consider creating a start-up script that runs at boot.  `man update-rc.d` for instructions.  Any system start-up scripts run as root.

Another alternative would be to start the script using "cron", using an "@reboot" field.  You can `man 5 crontab` for instructions on how to format your cron tab.  Root has a cron tab that runs things as ... root.  :)

Note that most of the solutions people provide here will require at least basic knowledge of how to get around on a command line.  The idea that you would "double-click a .sh file" is alien (or at least uncommon) to most folks who manage unix and linux systems.

Comment: +1 for the comment about double clicking a .sh file. :)  But I'm pretty sure Ubuntu is moving away from the old System-V style init scripts, so even though they are still supported, they may be obsolescent.  In order to weed out older users like me, they changed to [upstart](http://upstart.ubuntu.com/cookbook/).

Comment: Thanks for the link to upstart.  I do ubuntu things only rarely - most of my time is spent in Debian and FreeBSD.  <sigh>  More to learn....

Comment: My unfamiliarity with the stackexchange notifications caused me to see this answer just now. Getting around is alien to me at this point, and since the script gets the job done, I will have to stick with it until I have some free time to experiment and find the correct way to solve the problem.

Comment: @AnPel, no worries. :)  In retrospect, Graham's suggestion of using modprobe is probably the best one you've got here.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using `insmod`, you might want to consider using `modprobe` instead, for adding modules to your kernel.  Among other advantages, modprobe has a configuration file, `/etc/modprobe.conf`, in which you can specify modules to be loaded at boot.  Check out the [modprobe.conf man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man5/modprobe.conf.5.html) for further details.